# How to make all pixels of a button in CSS and HTML work, not just when clicking on button text

Tags: html, css

I have a button that should direct me to a certain page, and when I click it, it works. However, it only works when I click the actual text inside the button, not anywhere on the button itself.

I was able to find some CSS online for making a button, and I just edited it a bit, changed the color, radius, margins, and some other attributes. Here is the current CSS:

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 1.19rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  margin-left: 45vw;
  margin-right: 45vw;
  border: 3px solid black;
  outline: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">
  <a href="<insert-url-here>">Text Here</a>
</div>
```

Before I changed the CSS a bit, I could click anywhere on the button to go to the URL. However, after just changing the color and margins, which I don't think would cause this problem, I have to click on the text to go the URL, or else the button does nothing.

Comment: Why are you using a link inside a div as a "button" instead of a `<button>`?

Comment: `<a>` should be the wrapper, not the opposite.

Comment: @Md.RakibulIslam also, I'm a bit new to CSS and HTML, what would happen if I did write it as .btn a{...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you can use JS, just use a button

```
<button type='button' onclick="location.href='https://www.google.com'">
    Go to google
</button>
```

2. Use a form submit

```
<form action='https://www.google.com'>
    <button>Go to google</button>
</form>
```

3. Use an `a` by itself and style it accordingly

```
<a class='btn' href='https://www.google.com'>Go to google</a>
```

```
.btn {
    margin: 0 45vw;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 2rem;
    width: max-content;
    font-size: 1.19rem;
    background: black;
    border: 6px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Depending on how you're using it, you should also look into centering your element with `margin: auto`.

Lastly, the default button text color is black so if you use a button, you'll also want to either change the text color or change your black background, otherwise it will just look like a black box.

Comment: Thank you for this, I am building this website in Wordpress so the text color defaults to a reddish/pinkish color, so that is not a problem. However, I did try using `margin: auto` and it did nothing. I will try it again, but do you know any other way of centering it?

Comment: @Romit Ah if you're in Wordpress there's a host of factors that could be coming into play, would be hard to say without seeing it myself but you could do some googling.

Comment: @Cutler.Sheridan I agree Darryl gave advice when he downvoted unlike some other people on SO

Comment: @Romit The reason I have downvoted is because you shouldn't do so. It leads to many problems you don't even notice. One is that it doesn't behave as a link, therefore any link feature in the browser will not be available, e.g. links menus on right clicks, `ctrl`+`click` which opens the link in new tabs, link drag and drop, etc., All that without speaking of SEO problems, screen readers and a11y services and many stuff that won't work correctly. This is worse than a bad coding practice, it leads to problems.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 1.19rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  margin-left: 45vw;
  margin-right: 45vw;
  border: 3px solid black;
  outline: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<a href="<insert-url-here>" class="btn">Text Here</a>
```

Comment: Some explanation would make this a better answer. See [answer].